# How to compare request body in JSON and response body in JSON?

Tags: json, rest-assured

This is the example body we will be requesting and also received in response.
Please advise on how to validate the response body against request body

```
"Details": {
    "PaymentRequested": {
      "Transaction_Reference": "string",
      "Final_Reference": "string",
      "Payment Details": {
        "Amount": "0.10",
        "Currency": "INR" }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details...

Comment: I am writing automation test scripts, In the first call we receive the above mentioned as response body in JSON format. In the second call we send the same JSON BODY as request, at that time we have to validate with first call response and if it doesn't match it has to fail

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate), you can compare any JSON with any other JSON in one step. So this will be very easy.

```
* def json = { foo: 'world', hey: 'ho', zee: [1, 2, 3] }
* remove json.hey
* match json == { foo: 'world', zee: [1, 2, 3] }
```